# PHP MVC (Laravel), should I create another class instead of using the model if I'm not talking to the DB

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

I'm using Laravel and Eloquent (ORM) specifically, but I believe this to be a general MVC question...

I have a view and a couple of controller methods that receive an Eloquent Object, and can access the attributes by $foo->bar (again this is an Model Object).

I want to **re-use** these same views\controller methods with some objects that I create manually.  These objects will not be persisted to the DB, but they have the same design and structure as the Eloquent objects (they are essentially a heavily filtered\modified subset of data retrieved that I'm unable to re-create from an Eloquent statement).

Let's assume I have a Foo.php model that Eloquent uses.  For the manually created Foo object, should I use the Foo.php **model** or create another Foo.php **class**?

And specific to Laravel, where should this live and how to do I keep from being confused about which Foo I'm using?

In other words.  To re-use code (in view\controller) that receives and Eloquent (ORM) Object, should I create a new class for objects not retrieved from the DB (created manually), or should I use the existing model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the size of your project and how much you want to decouple the Eloquent from your views.

If this is a huge project that maybe in the future you would remove eloquent, so create a class that will be passed to the views as simple data objects.

If you think that eloquent is here to stay, so simply create manually the eloquent object and pass it to the views.

here are some of the options:

option 1: manually create eloquent object (without persisting)

```
$eloquentForView = new Whatever();
$eloquentForView->username = "just for view";
```

option 2: create an object specifically for your views

```
class WhateverDataView {
    public $username;
}
```

option 3: simply pass an array

- from eloquent object:

  ```
  $eloquentObj->toArray();
  ```
- simple code

  ```
  $dataForView = ['username'=>'whatever username'];
  ```

Comment: Should I manually create an Eloquent object if I'm not going to be persisted that data to the DB (rather it will only be passed to the view for the user to print).

Comment: or on 2nd though, should I just create an array for both instances and pass that through to the view? (this would just require more code)

Comment: just added some code, I would simply create an eloquent object manually without persisting, if you go on the first option...